# Extract First 6 Characters and Append Single Quote to Comma Separated Data SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure which is being passed IDs which are comma separated as follows

```
12345678,12345678,123456,12345
```

I need to extract the first six letters of each ID then append a single quote to each ID

Through research, i have managed to write a script to append quotes to the IDs. The code is

```
REPLACE(CONCAT('''', REPLACE(@ids, ',', ''','''), ''''),'\r\n','');
```

The code above is generating the following output

```
'12345678','12345678','123456','12345'
```

The actual output i want is

```
'123456','123456','123456','12345'
```

Comment: Are there always 4? You could use parsename()

Comment: No. The number varies based on the input entered by a user

Comment: You have several examples of answers, all of which some version of splitting the delimited text and recompiling it after modification.

Answer (score 1):

Use some sort of split function.  In the more recent versions of SQL Server, you can do:

```
select x.*
from (values ('12345678,12345678,123456,12345')) v(str) cross apply
     (select string_agg('''' + left(value, 6) + '''', ',') as s
      from string_split(v.str, ',')
     ) x;
```

You can do something similar in older versions, but the code is more cumbersome.

Comment: @db100 . . . String split is available.  You need to use the XML hack to re-aggregate the value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest passing a table valued parameter to your stored procedure, to move away from using CSV:

```
CREATE TYPE ValuesTableType AS TABLE (id INT, Val VARCHAR(50));

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.your_proc
@input_table ValuesTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT STRING_AGG('''' + Val + '''', ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id)
    FROM @input_table
```

The good thing about this approach is that it forces you to maintain a proper SQL table with values and their relative order.  With this information in place, it is much easier for the stored proc to generate the single quoted CSV output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option if you have a known or maximum number of elements

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values (1,'12345678,12345678,123456,12345')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select NewVal= Concat(
                           xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(6)')
                      ,','+xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(6)')
                      ,','+xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(6)')
                      ,','+xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(6)')
                      ,','+xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(6)')
                      ,','+xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(6)')
                      ,','+xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(6)')
                      ,','+xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(6)')
                      ,','+xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(6)')
                      )
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace(SomeCol,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  A(xDim)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  NewVal
1   123456,123456,123456,12345
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using Apply in the query:

```
   DECLARE @tbl AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '12345678,12345678,123456,12345'

SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + Tbl.IDs 
    FROM (
        SELECT '''' + SUBSTRING(b.Item,1,6) + '''' AS IDs
        FROM dbo.SplitString(@tbl,',') B
    ) Tbl FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS IdCol
```